# git checkout-index --prefix is smushing contents into prefix namespace

Tags: git, bash, svn

I am running a shell script on Windows that exports my git index into a temp svn trunk directory.

In a different project this script works fine, but in this project the --prefix smushes into the files I am unloading.

Here are my bash variables:

```
PLUGINSLUG="bbpress-live-topic-suggestions"
CURRENTDIR=`pwd`
MAINFILE="bbpress-live-topic-suggestions.php" # this should be the name of your main php file in the wordpress plugin


GITPATH="$CURRENTDIR" # this file should be in the base of your git repository
TEMPPATH="$GITPATH/tmp" # this should be the name of your main php file in the wordpress plugin


SVNPATH="$TEMPPATH/$PLUGINSLUG" # path to a temp SVN repo. No trailing slash required and don't add trunk.
SVNTRUNK="$TEMPPATH/$PLUGINSLUG/trunk/"
```

And here is the code I am using to copy the files from my base git directory into the svn

`git checkout-index -a -f --prefix=$SVNTRUNK`

And here is what the export looks like:

[image: http://content.screencast.com/users/adbox/folders/Jing/media/57952f28-34cb-4f0e-8368-3a5f66f19b87/2015-06-24_2051.png]

You can see it's ignoring the directory structure of my prefix. I've tried creating the /trunk/ folder before I run the command and it does not make a difference. I've even tried replacing the forward slashes in my variable to back slashes. The last /trunk/ part of the prefix is still not honored.

Once guess I have is that maybe the filepaths are too long and that is breaking it?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add backslashes to my forward slashes in my variable path.

```
SVNTRUNK="$TEMPPATH\/$PLUGINSLUG\/trunk/"
```